# Postfix. SMTP Access Policy protocol example develompent

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, policy, smtpd

I read http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html and to start develop a simple demo.

At first, i want get all key=value (http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html#protocol) from postfix to my script (i use perl).

I write simple code *user_ex.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $filename = '/tmp/log.log';
open my $file_,'>',$filename;
while (<STDIN>) {
 chomp;
 print $file_ , $_;
}
close $file_;
```

copy *user_ex.pl* to */usr/libexec/postfix/user_ex.pl*

add to end of *master.cf* two lines

```
user_ex  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/libexec/postfix/user_ex.pl
```

add to *main.cf*

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/user_ex
```

postfix restart, send email, and nothing..

File */tmp/log.log* have 0 bytes

1. What i can do wrong?
2. *unix:private/user_ex* - what does mean *private* ?

Comment: perl angle hints/fixes Try the script without `chomp` (to avoid I/O buffering) and use `$file_->print( $_);` (to print to $file_).

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I am tried. Nothing. I think the problem is not in the perl.

Comment: This is a complete example in perl. https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/examples/smtpd-policy/greylist.pl This should help. also how did u send the test mail?